# How do I recursively add ACL settings identical to the owners' for another user

Tags: linux, file-permissions, acl

I have a directory tree (in a Linux system) at "/opt/cudasamples" owned by root.
I wish to be able to change contents (files and subdirectories) of this directory as a normal user, i.e. without `sudo`'ing.
How can I add ACL settings to the directory and its contents to give my regular user account the same access privileges as root?
So, I am not looking to slacken the ordinary permissions on the tree to allow everyone to write. Rather, I am looking to give a specific user the same permissions as root in the tree.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To give a user account full permissions on a folder, use

```
setfacl -m useraccount:rwx folder
```

Use the `-R` parameter for recursive.

For more information, see [setfacl](https://linux.die.net/man/1/setfacl).

Comment: Does that set the execute bit "x" on all contained files as well as directories? I wouldn't want that for most of the files.  
Ideally I would like to set the permissions to the same as the owner's (root's), whatever they are.

Comment: From `man setfacl`: "execute only if the file is a directory or already has execute permission for some user (X)".